# Service Cloud Automation

Tags: case, bestpractice, service

I have been having real trouble managing Automation in my org.  I am the sole admin, with 20 users, around 5-10 are dedicated users managing around 3000 cases per month.  Almost all come from Email To Case.  A busy day is 300+ cases whilst normal days are 50-100.  We utilise the following features, case assignment rules, workflow rules (a few), process builder flows (a few) a single trigger to mainly prepare data in cases and route to Agents via Omni Channel.

I have recently been trying to improve this routing, mainly as it is queue based routing and we have users who maybe better suited to Skill based routing.  Unfortunately there is little management drive to use this and I have to agree it isn't as tidy for a small business like us.

My problem is I am really struggling to identify routing issues through the use of all the automation tools.  I wanted to know if it is considered best practice for suited admins to simply use triggers to manage everything?  I can probably move all of my process builder flow, workflow rules and case assignment rules to a trigger, test and deploy in 1-2 days and in my mind it is worth it.  Simply looking for words in email subjects to assign predefined field values and case ownership.

Can anyone share any best practice or advice?

I fear this maybe of topic as opinion based but I am hoping there is evidence to suggest what is considered best practice.

Answer (score 1):

So -- if going the trigger route, consider decoupling the problem wherein Apex is used to derive keywords (because Apex has superior string handling tools to WFRs or PBs).

Then use Case Assignment rules to work off the keywords.  This gives you the best of both worlds - easily understandable and changeable assignment rules and deep parsing technology when you need it.

*Not directly related to your question, but agent productivity can be improved with macros and quick text. You can also leverage Salesforce 
 Knowledge.*